# What is shared between multiple windows in an electron app?

Tags: javascript, electron

I have an electron app which works fine as a single application. I use pubsub-js to push messages from components for other bits of the UI to handle without being tightly coupled. I use an MVVM framework so I use this event system to communicate between view components without them all being linked to each other, I do use IPC events for some electron messages but generally I just use that for low level events, and pubsub for view level events for only view components to listen for.

Now the problem seems to arise when I want to support multiple windows, as for example if I go and try to save on window 1, it seems to actually run the save on window 2, as well as notifications from window 1 ending up on window 2, so it seems to share some sort of state across applications.

Also another problem I just noticed, if I were to create window 2 from window 1, then I were to close window 2, the native menu bar in windows 1 stops functioning and just throws exceptions.

So what exactly gets shared between multiple electron windows and what is the best practice for isolating this sort of behaviour?

Comment: I didn' expected this behavior, I always thought, that there is nothing shared between the windows expect the main Process which is creating those windows.
So I always used the ipc module to build communication between windows

Comment: Currently I do not want any communication between windows, I was hoping they would all be isolated, but it appears by default they are sharing the same node instance although its hard to tell.

Comment: Which MVVM framework are you using? I assume that the global context (`window`) is unique to each browser window and that might cause you problems.

Comment: I am using Knockout, but its not a problem specific to that, for example if window 1 creates window 2, then I close window 2, the menu bar in windows 1 no longer functions. So the issue seems to be with Electron doing *something* I am not expecting behind the scenes.